# Bedroom window opening into garage

Tags: doors, windows, code-compliance

We have a window in our bedroom that is opening into our garage. As you could tell, the garage was an afterthought by the previous owners. Unfortunately, they put little to no thought as to how this affects the master bedroom window!

I am located in the Southeast of USA, so the building code requires an egress for a room to qualify as a bedroom (or something to that effect? I am no expert by any means, some insight on this will be appreciated). We do have an attached master bathroom with two windows, one of which is obviously an egress. But at it's current state, the window in our bedroom is by no means one, for the following reasons:

1. The window has a window unit in it (We do not have central air, but we are planning on spending the money to get this done soon)
2. The window opens into the garage, which is technically not the outside to which you'd go to escape a fire or other hazard
3. The garage roof is much shorter than the bedroom ceiling, which means, the bottom half of the window is looking **into** the garage and the top half is looking **over** the roof of the garage! (*sigh, I know, this is a mess*)

My questions are:

1. Does this window qualify as an egress? If I get inspected, will they make me either tear down the garage or move the window? There is no other wall to move this to, unfortunately, but still.
2. Am I legally allowed to just remove this window and make it a wall instead? I would very much like to not be looking at the garage roof when in bed.
3. The window currently is 3' from the floor. The garage roof view begins at the 6' mark. There is a foot more of window after this mark, so I see one foot into the garage roof and about 3' into the garage. Given this, would I be able to do a different kind of window that is ALL at the garage roof level instead? Maybe a long window that you can escape out of and be on the roof of the garage? Or is this too high to qualify as an egress? (6 feet from the floor)
4. Given my goal is to not have a stupid window looking over the garage roof in my master bed, could I just swap this out to a door instead? Will this pass inspection and look better? I believe this adds SOME functionality, as I can go in and use my tools and woodwork in there and easily walk in to wash myself off or what-not. But the problem is, my door should not be above the garage roof, which means I am left with a 6' high door. Will this look stupider? Would it be beneficial to maybe add some stairs to step down into the garage area, THEN install a door? Make a little section from my bedroom INTO the garage and have a door all inside the garage?

I am trying to figure out what I could do about this window and have it not be an eyesore. Currently, the window unit is blocking the fact that this window looks into the garage. But when I install central air, this window unit will be off and it will look very idiotic! Any suggestions on how to improve this situation is much appreciated!

EDIT: WE DO NOT park our car in the garage. The garage is where we work out and where we woodwork. There are no risks of fumes, besides maybe sawdust, which can be easily handled with some dust collection system. This was a concern to everyone responding, so I figured I would clarify!

Comment: A second door should work as an egress.  They are mainly worried about you having a second way to get out instead of how it looks.  Would be nice when you can't sleep to do woodwork without needing to get dress to go outside.

Comment: are you suggesting a door between garage and bedroom? toxic fumes from car exhaust or from workshop solvents and paints will likely seep into your bedroom, even with the door closed. Ok into a hallway but not where you sleep.

Comment: I rarely use any substances that emit toxic fumes (I like using food-grade mineral oils for almost all my work), and if I am using anything toxic, I do it way out in the backyard, over a tarp, away from where any of us reside.

Comment: Usually the wall between a garage and house needs to be fire rated. A window isn’t. You may need to frame out the garage door area to make it unambiguously not a garage.

Comment: @JonCuster -- yeah, never mind that an opening between a bedroom and a garage is strictly prohibited by R302.5.1.  One *could* have a fixed window using fire-*resistive* glazing and a matching frame, but an operable opening would strictly be prohibited by Code (fire resistive glazing and frames are tested to the firewall standard, so they aren't openings for Code's sake)

Comment: You have a chance at succeeding if you first convert this space from garage to ante-room, workshop or whatever. You can make it comply with building codes by proper insulation and fenestration. This matters for insurance and could be a valuable upgrade. Whether it is permitted is another question and depends on your local ordinance. This might matter for resale. Which route do you want to go?

Comment: This is far too many questions in one. Needs to be edited down to focus on one thing at a time.

Comment: @P2000 - VERY GOOD advice! I do have something similar in mind, where we basically just tear this garage down completely (or just modify the roof to a gazebo-like roof and screen the walls instead) and make it a nice outdoor patio that I can exit from my bedroom. Turning it into a nice workshop with insulation is a MUCH better idea. I will explore this option!

Comment: @JonCuster - This is also very much in the books. My concern with that is, if I were to do this, then this becomes a part of the house, a room, that I can go into through my bedroom. This "room" will break other codes, like the floor being at the same level as the ground, or the height of the room being too short. Would the idea suggested by P2000 circumvent these issues? Or am I looking at walling the garage door, raising the floor, and raising the ceiling?

Comment: Your local authority may rather insist that you demolish the illegal addition...

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple problems with the window in the bedroom. Besides the esthetic issues it is a source of carbon monoxide from the garage. You may be able to get a sliding window in that bedroom wall, but not likely and perhaps not at the required sill height.  What is the smallest size egress window? 5.7 sq
In order to meet baseline requirements, egress windows must meet the following standards: Minimum width of opening: 20 in. Minimum height of opening: 24 in. Minimum net clear opening: 5.7 sq.Ft. (note :that does not mean that a 20"x 24" opening is acceptable.) The figures are the min. Minimum width and height multiplied by the corresponding dimension must = 5.7 sq.ft. So quick math says that if you can fit a single hung window that's 48 inches tall it will have to be 36 inches wide. to have the opening meet the code. You can go with a smaller opening (5sq.ft.) if the sill height is at floor level or below grade. But then again you have the garage issue.
Perhaps the better solution would be a removal of the window and placing a door in the master bath.
Your local community codes may also be more restrictive. You should ask this of the local building department. I am shocked at how the situation you have was allowed to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the specific dimensions! Unfortunately, the garage does not go all the way to the bathroom. It stops where the bedroom stops. If I were to install a door there, it will open in my backyard, directly behind the garage wall. Would a few steps to walk down into the garage from the bedroom, THEN a door be good? I can wall this mini-hallway into the garage then install a door there.

Answer (score -2):

I would start with why do you care about the code?  This really only matters if you are going to rent the house out or are planning a remodel.  I promise that there are millions of homes with window units in a bedroom's only window (or no window at all).  If you're concerned about safety, I think your bathroom window should suffice for escape.

If you have a bedroom without an external wall, so I'm not sure about what to do about the aesthetics of a window to the garage.  You could cut in another window if you do have an external wall and sheetrock over the one you have.  A door is an option, not sure it buys you much, are you sure you are even out of code for your community?

Comment: the fire & liability insurance cares

Comment: I do believe I am non-compliant. The garage was built with little to no concern to codes. The MAIN electric wire that comes to my house from the grid is about a foot above the roof of the garage, which is also not code-compliant. I was clearly told when I purchased this house that this garage was 100% not built with any inspections and might become an issue at some point in the future.